# Type safe string interpolation in swift

Tags: swift

I have code that looks something like:

```
var link = "http://example.com/images/\(myFoo)_pattern.html"
myCustomObject.link = link
```

The problem is that I encountered a strange bug, this link is set from multiple places - sometimes `myFoo` is an `Optional` so I end up getting `../Optional('realValue')_pattern.html` instead of `realValue_pattern.html`.

Basically interpolation is involved, the string "unwraps incorrectly" in my case. I know the workaround (to make sure not to pass optionals in those places) but when I pass these values incorrectly I have no type error or compiler warning.

Basically, I want a type safe alternative that would prevent these PBKAC errors from happening again. Optimally, I want to know if there is a way to perform string interpolation in a way that would not cause these unintended results but still be easy to use.

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: I don't think swift compiler allows it to happen i.e. myFoo is both optional or not at the same time. How did you declare myFoo?

Comment: This is a poor design choice by the creators of Swift to make it part of the value's description.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you would like a way to eliminate `Optional()` from the string interpolation of variables without knowing ahead of time whether they are optionals or not.  One approach is to define a postfix operator `&` that you can put after all variables that does string interpolation the way you want.

Here is an example of the problem:

```
var str1: String = "bye"
var str2: String! = "hello"
var str3: String? = "aloha"

println("\(str1) \(str2) \(str3)")  // prints "bye hello Optional("aloha")"
```

Define the postfix operator `&` for all types:

```
postfix operator & {}

postfix func & <T>(s: T?) -> String {
    return (s == nil) ? "nil" : "\(s!)"
}

postfix func & <T>(s: T) -> String {
    return "\(s)"
}
```

Then follow your vars with `&` when you do string interpolation:

```
println("\(str1&) \(str2&) \(str3&)")  // prints "bye hello aloha"
```

Then, if you can remember to use `&`, you won't have to worry what type of value they are and they will still work if you change them to an optional type in the future.

Comment: "Then, if you can remember to use &" - is there any way to gain the inverse? That is, to not be able to forget to use a specific syntax because doing so would result in a compile error? I can use `!` right now. (Nice use of rule resolution btw)

Comment: The advantage of `&` over `!` is you don't need to know if`myFoo` is an optional.  Just always put it on.

Comment: I can't think of any way to enforce this with a compile error.  There may be a way to just change string interpolation of optionals, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming myFoo is an optional, you only need to do it:

```
var link = "http://example.com/images/\(myFoo!)_pattern.html" // note '!'
myCustomObject.link = link
```